# Handle edge case of not adding extra node in sum of linked lists (Leetcode's 2. Add Two Numbers)

Tags: python, linked-list

I was trying solve Leetcode's question [2 Add Two Numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/). The question has a solution but I already started with my own implementation and I see where the mistake is but I am unclear on how to solve the problem.

The line `total.next = ListNode(0)` is where the issue lies. I am creating an extra `0` at the end of the linked list of the answer but I shouldn't be doing so.

```
Input: 
    list1 = 2->4->3 
    list2 = 5->6->4

Expected Output: 7->0->8
Explanation:     342 + 465 = 807

My output:       7->0->8->0
```

However, I have no way of backtracking when I am at the end. How could I do this?

I am also moving the pointer passed to me for the two linked lists but I am less worried about this. However, I do have a question. Is this a mistake because linked lists are objects here and so Python would pass them by reference and so whatever function that called `addTwoNumbers` would have pointers to the 2 linked lists point to `None`?

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        
        total = ListNode(0)
        totalHead = total
        carry = 0
        
        while list1 or list2:
            if not list1:
                digitSum = carry + list2.val
                list2 = list2.next
            elif not list2:
                digitSum = carry + list1.val
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                digitSum = carry + list1.val + list2.val
                list1 = list1.next
                list2 = list2.next
            
            total.val = digitSum % 10
            carry = digitSum // 10
            
            total.next = ListNode(0) ## I have to create a node later but at the end, I have an extra zero
            total = total.next
            
        if carry > 0:
            total.next = ListNode(carry)
        
        return totalHead
```

Comment: "I have to create a node later [...]" Why?

Comment: To put in the value of `carry`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid creating a node that you have to delete later. So instead of creating a node *before* the loop starts, and also at the very end of each iteration, create a node within each iteration, at the moment you know which value it will get. This makes it necessary to distinguish between creating the *first* node and the others, as you need to initialise the head reference to the first node once it is created, but this is only a small matter:

```
class Solution(object):
    def addTwoNumbers(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        total = None
        totalHead = None
        carry = 0

        while list1 or list2:
            if not list1:
                digitSum = carry + list2.val
                list2 = list2.next
            elif not list2:
                digitSum = carry + list1.val
                list1 = list1.next
            else:
                digitSum = carry + list1.val + list2.val
                list1 = list1.next
                list2 = list2.next

            newNode = ListNode(digitSum % 10)  # Only create node here! just-in-time...
            carry = digitSum // 10
            if totalHead:
                total.next = newNode
            else:  # Only for first iteration:
                totalHead = newNode
            total = newNode

        if carry > 0:
            total.next = ListNode(carry)
            
        return totalHead
```

Unrelated, but you can simplify a bit the `if...elif...else` construct:

```
            digitSum = carry
            if list1:
                digitSum += list1.val
                list1 = list1.next
            if list2:
                digitSum += list2.val
                list2 = list2.next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a lot of boilerplate code and improve readability by using a helper generator function and `itertools.zip_longest`. `divmod` saves another line:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        def i(n):
            while n:
                yield n.val
                n = n.next
        
        carry = 0
        result = node = None
        for x, y in zip_longest(i(l1), i(l2), fillvalue=0):
            carry, dig = divmod(x+y+carry, 10)
            new = ListNode(dig)
            if node:
                node.next = new
            node = new
            if not result:
                result = new
        
        if carry:
            node.next = ListNode(carry)
        
        return result
```